# Eclipse - Why Errors with Android SDK for normal user but not root?

Tags: android, eclipse

Why doesn’t this error happening when starting Eclipse as a normal user, but doesn’t when starting as sudo:

[image]

I have checked the permission of all directories that I can imagine that might be affected and chowned to my user and group id.

These are the root directories of all areas that I’m familiar with:

```
Folder                   Specification
-------------------------------------------------------------
/opt/android/sdk          Android SDK
/opt/eclipse/eclipse      Eclipse
~/myeclipse               Eclipse specific configuration area
~/workspace               Source workspace
```

These are the commands that were issues to ensure that My user and group ID are assigned:

```
$ sudo chown -R ljames:ljames /opt/android/sdk
$ sudo chown -R ljames:ljames /opt/eclipse/eclipse
$ sudo chown -R ljames:ljames ~/myeclipse
$ sudo chown -R ljames:ljames ~/workspace
```

Can someone tell me what else might be causing this possible
permission issue?

I also executed this command on all the subdirectories to find any file or directory not belonging to my user ID.

```
$ sudo find /opt/android/sdk ! -user ljames 
$ sudo find /opt/eclipse/eclipse ! -user ljames 
$ sudo find ~/myeclipse ! -user ljames 
$ sudo find ~/workspace ! -user ljames
```

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, this is a permissions problem.  Root is not troubled by permissions; others are.  Actually, there's one exception: at least one execute bit S_IXUSR|S_IXGRP|S_IXOTH in the permissions field ( di_flags & ~(S_IFMT) ) must be on for users--EVEN ROOT--to execute a program.  This used to be true for "executing" (viz., searching) a directory, but no longer is.  Note that I parenthesized S_IFMT because one should always be ultra-defensive when incorporating macros in expressions: they can be a source of obscure bugs.

I suspect the problem might be something that's superficially subtle but really isn't if you know how directory permissions work.  I would be willing to BET MONEY that some directory somewhere is SEARCHABLE to your non-root programmer but is not READABLE.  The difference is that "search" enables you to locate an entry of known name within a directory, whereas "read" enables you to browse the directory like an open catalog.  In order to discover whole sets of files, say, *.java, that can be scanned sequentially for, say, the body of a given function, the containing directory must be READable as well as SEARCHable.

Comment: Thanks! I updated my question with corrections.  I had mistakenly left the "-R" out when typing the commands I executed.  When running as root quite a number of files becomes owned by root.  After running the `chown -R` back to my user ID non are owned by root.  It's my understanding that the owner of a file has full permissions to executing it if it's an executioner file.  I agree that it's most likely some permission issue.  But I can't figure out what files needs to be checked other than the ones I listed in the question.

Comment: Good first post, it is just a little hard to read.  Please just consider reading the [markdown formatting guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)